# Please recommend PDU SMS format code or library for .NET or C++

Tags: c#, sms, pdu

I have been searching a lot for a chunk of code, or a library to format SMS messages in PDU format and had little luck. They were either huge monsters with terrific dependencies on everything way above my requirements and a very obscure interface, totally not justifying the straight-forward, although rather complex encoding.

Being on the edge of creating a NIH, my question is - have encountered the same problem and how have you solved it?

Comment: although I accepted an answer, I am not satisfied with what we have. the accepted answer can only decode, but not encode PDU. GSMComm is plain impossible, and what looks as the only reasonable alternative, with all due sorrow, is writing my own library.

Answer (score 1):

[GSMComm](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm#gsmcomm) has a PDU conversion class for wroking with SMS Messages.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15924/Library-for-Decode-Encode-SMS-PDU

I use this library to encode and decode messages. It also works with multi-part messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/PDUDecoder.aspx