# How to send multipart/concatenated SMS to phone using AT command?

Tags: c#, sms, multipart, gateway, at-command

I got a computer with a nokia hooked up to it, and using AT Commands I managed to send text messages through my C# program (using TEXT MODE AT COMMANDS, NOT PDU). It's all working fine and I can recieve messages as well.

I do wish to be able to send a text thats longer than 160 characters. And for that I need to be able to send a multipart SMS. I've searched around for this and my mate has told me that I need to check the header information in bytes on my "long" message, I analyzed the header information on a recieved long text which was: 233 64 248 104 38 32 161. But that doesn't really get me close to being able to send or recieve multipart texts.

Which header information is needed to do this? And how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

The headers on an SMS are well described with worked examples here:
http://www.spallared.com/old_nokia/nokia/smspdu/smspdu.htm

The specifics of the header for a multipart SMS are given in the Wikipedia page about concatenated SMS:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS

Comment: Yeah but the SMS headers are for PDU (and I can't find a decent PDU encoder/decoder for C#), isn't it possible to work some headers for TEXT mode?

Comment: You can't send multipart messages in text mode, you will need to switch to PDU mode. Sorry, I should have been clearer about that in my answer.

Comment: No problem. Could you perhaps help me find a PDU encoder for C#? Cause PDU format is quite confusing? Thanks for all your help

Comment: A quick google turns up lots of possibilities, including http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/samples.htm#pdu , http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2009/02/sending-sms-in-cnet-using-gsm-modem-and.html , http://csharpfeeds.com/post/2139/Library_for_decodeencode_sms_PDU.aspx , and also this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658575/please-recommend-pdu-sms-format-code-or-library-for-net-or-c++