# SIM900 - Send SMS over 160 characters using Gammu

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gsm, at-command, sim900, gammu

I am using raspberry
 Pi 3 for sending SMS using SIM900A. I configured Gammu to send SMS via SIM900A and it worked fine. But I was able to send only 156 characters(Max). I need to send more than 200 characters.

Command I used : " echo 'MESSAGE' | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT +91XXXXXXXXXX"

Is there any way to do that? I am open for both AT commands and Gammu way.

Thanks in advance...

P.S : I would prefer TEXT format than PDU

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send multipart/concatenated SMS to phone using AT command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358758/how-to-send-multipart-concatenated-sms-to-phone-using-at-command)

Comment: _"P.S : I would prefer TEXT format than PDU" then I'm afraid it is not possible. Not on SIM900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

Please try this.

```
echo 'MESSAGE' | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT +91XXXXXXXXXX" -len 400
```

Internally gammu sends more than one message if it is greater than 156 characters, but that is transparent to you. You only send a message with that command of up to 400 characters, and the phone receives 1 SMS only.